# X86 Assembly - Segmentation Fault Passing Array To Function?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

Using GDB I see where the segmentation fault happens when it executes "call Mby5" but even debugging it, I don't see why it's getting a segmentation fault when I call the function?

In this code I have two arrays, the first I print to the screen and then the second "ard2" I want to multiply the values of the first one by 5 and then store those new values in "ard2" and then print them. The Mby5 function is where I'm trying to multiply them and store the new values inside ard2, then return and call PrintArray.  Here is the complete code and will attach a screenshot of GDB showing when the error hits.

```
section .data 
    msg1: db 'Here are the array element values: ',10, 0 
    msgL1: equ $-msg1

    msg2: db"Here are the new array element values after multiplying by 5! ",10, 0
    msgL2: equ $-msg2

    ard1: dd 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 20, 40
    ard1L: equ ($-ard1) / 4 ; Number of elments = array length / 4

    ard2: dd 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ard2L: equ ($-ard2) / 4 ; Number of elments = array length / 4


section .text 
    global _start ; declare _start as a global label
_start:
    push ebp        ; save ebp for whoever called main function (OS or other program)
    mov ebp, esp    ; create our new stack frame

   mov ecx,msg1 ; print message #1
   mov edx,msgL1
   call PString

   ;save array base address in ebx and save size of the array in ecx
   mov ebx, ard1
   mov ecx, ard1L

   ;call PrintArray to print the array element
   call PrintArray

   ;print message2
   mov ecx, msg2
   mov edx, msgL2
   call PString

   ;restore the array address and its size to the stack before calling Mby5 function
   mov ebx, ard1
   mov ecx, ard1L
   call Mby5  **[ERROR HAPPENS WHEN I CALL IT HERE]**
    
  ;After multplfying array1 elements by 5 and storing it in ard2 we call PrintArray and pass it ard2
  mov ebx, ard2
  mov ecx, ard2L

  ;Call PrintArray 
  call PrintArray

PrintArray:
    section .text
        push ebp 
        mov ebp, esp

top:
    mov eax,[ebx] ;move the value of [ebx] to eax
    call printDec
    call println
    add ebx, 4
    loop top

    mov esp, ebp ; destroy the stack
    pop ebp
    ret

Mby5:  
    section .text
      push ebp
      mov ebp, esp

top1:
    mov eax, [ebx] ; access first array element. Move its value to eax
    shl eax, 2 ; multiply by 4
    add eax, [ebx] ; multiply by 5
    mov [ard2 + ebx - ard1], eax ; store the result in array2
    add ebx, 4
    loop top1

    popa ;restore registers
    ret


println:
    section .data
    nl db"", 10 
    section .text
        ;save register values of the called function
        pusha
        mov ecx, nl
        mov edx, 1
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        int 80h

        ;restore the old register values of the called function
        popa 
        ret

PString:
    ;Save register values of called function
    pusha

    mov eax, 4  ;use 'write' system call = 4
    mov ebx, 1  ;file descriptor 1 = STDOUT
    int 80h     ;call the kernel

    ;restore the old register values of the called function
    popa
    ret


printDec:
    section .bss
        decstr resb 10;
        ct1 resd 1

    section .text
        pusha ;save all registers

        mov dword[ct1], 0 ; assume initially 0
        mov edi, decstr ;edi points to dec-string in memory
        add edi, 9 ;moved to the last element of string
        xor edx, edx

whileNotZero:
        mov ebx, 10 ;get ready to divide by 10
        div ebx ;divide by 10
        add edx,'0' ; convert to ascii char
        mov byte[edi], dl ; put it in string
        dec edi ;move to next char in string
        inc dword[ct1]
        xor edx, edx ;clear edx
        cmp eax, 0 ;is remainder 0
        jne whileNotZero ; keep looping

        inc edi ; conversion finish
        mov ecx, edi
        mov edx, [ct1]
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        int 0x80

        popa ;restore registers
        ret
```

Error Picture

[image: Error]

Stepped through with GDP and checked register values. Can't seem to find the issue.

---

I changed Mby5 but using leave and ret

```
    Mby5:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov edi, 0 ; index variable
top1:
    mov eax, [ebx] ; access first array element. Move its value to eax
    shl eax, 2 ; multiply by 4
    add eax, [ebx] ; multiply by 5
    mov [ard2 + ebx - ard1], eax ; store the result in array2
    add ebx, 4
    loop top1

    leave ; restore the original stack frame before returning
    ret
```

But then my output is

```
 Here are the new array element values after multiplying by 5! 
10
20
30
40
50
100
200
10
0
825360384
2356
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
zsh: segmentation fault
```

Comment: Since you are already in gdb, look what the faulting instruction is. E.g. `x/i $pc` Note that `next` will not step into functions so that doesn't tell you how far it got in `Mby5`

Comment: One obvious issue is that your epilogue in `Mby5` does not match the prologue (you have a `popa` at the end).

Comment: I stepped into it and even executing each instruction it doesn't generate the error. It's like when I call it it's not passing the correct memory address or something.

Comment: Like Jester said, the `ret` at the end will return to the wrong place because you ran it while ESP wasn't pointing to the return address pushed by the `call`.  So the actual segfault isn't until after the `ret`, when the CPU tries to fetch code from a bad address.  But the fix for that is to balance the stack.  Normally you can let functions clobber some registers, so you don't need slow pusha/popa, e.g. EAX, ECX, and EDX are normally call-clobbered.

Comment: It's most likely faulting on the ret.

Comment: How exactly do I fix this then. Even if I remove return from top1 all together it still gives the segmentation fault.

Comment: Do you understand how `popa` does not match the `push ebp; mov ebp, esp` at  the start? Replace those two with a `pusha` if you don't care about `ebp` (which you don't seem to).

Comment: I did that, but not I'm running into some issue with the loop not terminating.

Comment: This tends to become an online debug session. ^^ I suggest to close this question, fix the stack alignment issues and open a new one should need be. We'll still be here.

Comment: After the final `call PrintArray` you have no ending, so you fall through into `PrintArray` again. You need to insert an `exit` syscall.

Comment: Didn't even notice that. Thank you! I still get quite confused with working with the stack.  Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you 'hide' the instructions from Mby5 that don't have to do with the stack, this remains:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

...

popa ;restore registers
ret
```

Obviously the `popa` isn't matched by an appropriate number of pushed bytes. This leads to the call address being removed from the stack before the `ret` is reached, and so the call returns to a dubious address.

You fix this by aligning push and pop instructions, like:

```
push ebp
pusha
...
popa
pop ebp
ret
```

or just

```
pushad
...
popad
```

Comment: I see what you're saying, just a little confused on how to fix this and properly return after storing all the new numbers to ard2

Comment: I updated the function and showed my output. Both the way in my updated version and doing what you just did gives the same output. Like it's not properly terminating in the loop

Comment: Jester help me realize I didn't have an exit statement. Thank you for the help as well though.